# Tracking aggregates in MongoDB in near real-time

Tags: mongodb

We need to track record counts for records in an Accounts collection, based on a 'type' field.  So we want to know how many Accounts are in TYPE1, how many are in TYPE2, etc...  Further, we need to know the totals of a 'amount' field inside each Account.

Aggregate queries aren't going to be fast enough for us (these counts need to update in real-time in the UI and we will have 10s of millions of records, aggregate queries that take many seconds to run aren't going to cut it), so I'm looking at having a separate totals collection with an object that tracks counters for each type.

As we change the value of the 'type' field (i.e. move the account from one type to another), we need to adjust the counts and 'value' totals (decrement the counter for the original type, increment the counter for the new type).  We can then use an update command with $incr() to adjust the fields in the totals record that stores the type counts and value sums.  (This does mean that we have two database writes for every 'type' update, but I don't see a way around this unless anyone has a suggestion).

For single record adjustments, this is pretty straightforward - we can just trap the type change in our data access layer and make a secondary update in the totals tracking object.

The problem is how to track the 'amount' totals.  For single record adjustments, this isn't a problem.  But for bulk operations (db.collection.update() that could effect many thousands of records), we need to get the total of the 'amount' field for each of the adjusted records.

So far, I haven't been able to easily find a way to get Mongo to get the information that I need.

I've got one strategy worked out that involves adding a tagged history array in the Account object with a unique "changeId" and the 'amount' the document record had at the time of the change, then running an aggregate against that history record for the changeId to get the totals.  Then optionally delete the history record (or do that in a periodic clean-up process).

For example, if I did a bulk change, I'd generate a unique ID ('aaaaaaaa' in the following), then do an array insert for a history record as part of the bulk update that adjusts the 'type':

```
{
  "amount": 123,
  "type": "TYPE1",
  "history": [
     {
       "changeId": "aaaaaaaaaa",
       "amount": 123,
       "oldType": "TYPE2",
       "newType": "TYPE1"
     }
  ]
}
```

Then I can do an aggregate that gives me the sum of the 'amount' for the changeId that just ran.

I think this will work, but it's clumsy - is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "bulk"? Is it db.collection.update() with many=True or db.collection.bulkWrite?

Comment: db.collection.update() with a query set that could anywhere between 10 and hundreds of thousands of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct is to store a change log in a separate collection but I don't see a way to do that in the MongoDB bulk collection documentation.  I agree that the work of maintaining the aggregates needs to be in a separate process.  Your idea of creating a history array in the account collection can work.  I don't know your application but I would slightly change the structure to avoid a timing hole. I'd create a ticker tape of changes the aggregate process can apply with little knowledge of the account.

```
{
 "amount": active amount,
 "type":  active type,
 "history" [
   {
     "changeId": "aaaaaaaa",
     "NewType": 1    
     "amount": new amount
   },
   {
     "changeId": "aaaaaaaa",
     "OldType":  -1
     "amount": old amount as a negative value     
   }
  ]
}
```

The reason is because of the timing of the aggregate collection process.  Using your original structure, it has to get the new amount from the account itself.  But what if the account changes again before the aggregate collection process runs.  Say, the transactions are as follows:

```
Type1 2000
Changes to Type2 3000
Changes to Type1 1000
```

Using the following structure, your aggregate process has to figure out to ignore the type 2 change because it cancels itself out.

```
{
  "amount": 1000
  "type":   Type1
  "history" [
   {
     "changeID": "aaaaaa",
     "amount": 2000
     "oldtype": Type1
     "newtype": Type2
   },
   { 
     "changeID": "bbbbbb",
     "amount": 3000
     "oldtype": Type2
     "newtype": Type1
   }
 ]
}
```

I'd do the following.  The aggregate process is going to find all Type1 records in the history and perform the aggregate.  So for Type1, it is going to sum 1 and -1 for no difference in the count and -2000 and 1000 to decrement the Type1 amount by 1000.  The Type2 aggregate will cancel out.

```
{
"amount": 1000
"type":   Type1
"history" [
    {
      "changeID": "aaaaaa",
      "Type1":  -1
      "amount": -2000
    },
   {
     "changeID": "aaaaaa",
     "Type2":  1
     "amount": 3000
   },
   {
     "changeID": "bbbbbb",
     "Type2":  -1
     "amount": -3000
   },
   {
     "changeID": "bbbbbb",
     "Type1":  1
     "amount": 1000
   }
 ]
}
```

No matter what you choose to do, you'll need to determine which history records have already been processed.  You can either delete the history documents once processed, flag them, or move them to an audit collection.

Comment: Could you provide some code illustrating extraction of amount deltas and writing some changes into a separate object?

Comment: But how do I get the values for the change amounts?  Consider the scenario where we are updating 500 records from Type1 to Type2 using db.collection.update().  A naive approach would be to run an aggregate over those 500 records to get the net change, then do the bulk update of those 500 records, then update the aggregate summation collection.  But this isn't an atomic operation, and some of those 500 records might be changed in between operations. That's why I'm talking about storing the change history in the Account object itself (that way at least it is atomically captured).

Comment: ok - this is in line with what I have in mind.  Note that I'm intending to run the aggregate immediately after the bulk update, and limit the aggregate to the specific changeId.  Otherwise, the timing on the aggregate becomes super tricky. It would be nice if there was a way to configure the database to do this itself - I know that Mongo just added support for multi-document transactions (still don't think it would address this use-case, though). And I considered using Mongo change callbacks - but if we have 10 app servers running, each would get the callback...  Thanks!